# Swift - KeyboardWillHide and KeyboardDidShow notification firing at almost same time

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, nsnotifications

I'm trying to use Keyboard Notifications so I can move my information on the scroll view up or down depending whether the keyboard will appear or will hide. My problem is when I do the first click on any textfield. I can't understand why it fires the KeyboardWillHide's notification right when KeyboardDidShow's notification fires...

This is the relevant code.

```
func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func unregisterKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    NSLog("Keyboard did show")
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    NSLog("Keyboard will hide")
}
```

This is the output that gives:

[image]

Comment: The console shows `keyboardWillHide` firing one second later — not at the same time.

Comment: you right thanks, but it wasn't very helpful at all @TroyT

Comment: Well "at the same time" and one second later are very different.

Comment: Once again I believe that you are totally right indeed. Already edited the title :) @TroyT